# Is this the best way to reverse a string in C (not in place)?

Tags: c, strings

Here is my code. Is there anyway to make it more efficient?

```
/*
IN: string to have characters reversed
OUT: string containing characters in reversed order
*/
char* reverStr(const char *str)
{
        char* revStr = (char*)malloc(strlen(str));
        int i;
        for(i = strlen(str)-1; i >= 0; i--)
            revStr[strlen(str)-1-i] = str[i];
        return revStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen()` is expensive, don't use it inside the loops. Use `size_t` for indices. Don't hesitate to use auxiliary variables. Oh, and the string has to be null-terminated.

```
/*
IN: string to have characters reversed
OUT: string containing characters in reversed order
*/
char* reverStr(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);        
    char* revStr = (char*)malloc(len + 1);

    size_t dst, src;
    for (dst = len - 1, src = 0; src < len; src++, dst--) {
        revStr[dst] = str[src];
    }
    revStr[len] = '\0';
    return revStr;
}
```

Comment: I thought the optimizer does that sort of thing in c?

Comment: @Celeritas: only if the compiler can determine that `strlen()` has no side effects and the the result does not change during the loop. I would not count of that complicated auto-optimizations.

Comment: You mean cahcing the return value of the function? I've just checked, and VS2010 C compiler with `/O2` flag produces practically identical binaries for your original code and the variant of mine. So yes, it apparently does, but... I wouldn't rely on it. `strlen()` is a standard function and it can be treated by the compiler specially, and such optimization is not guaranteed.

Comment: By the way, even with `/O2`, if you turn `Enable intrinsic functions` off, then `stlren()` gets inlined twice, and no memoization of its result occurs.

Comment: Question: how is it faster to use two variables for the `dst` and `src` instead of using math and having 1 variable?

Comment: @Celeritas The perfect algorithm of optimizing register usage was discovered by the end of the seventies; every optimizing compiler implements it, because local integer variables don't even have to go on the stack.

Comment: @Joker_vD what is the name of the algorithm you refer to? I'm curious how something can be proven to be perfect?

Comment: @Celeritas G. J. Chaitin, "Register Allocation & Spilling via Graph Coloring". Okay, that's the beginning of the eighties, and there was future development to increase the algorithm's speed (it's important for jitters).

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
/*
IN: string to have characters reversed
OUT: string containing characters in reversed order
*/
char* reverStr(const char *str)
{
        int index=strlen(str);
        char* revStr = (char*)malloc(index--);
        int destIndex=0;
        while (0<=index)
            revStr[destIndex++] = str[index--];
        revStr[destIndex]=0; 
        return revStr;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Cave: `malloc` does not fill the allocated space with zeros (by itself) - the operating system does though. But I would add `\0` explicitely at the end.

Comment: @Lilith2k3: You are right, I added it. The same problem has the implementation given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative:

```
char* reverStr(const char *str)
{
  size_t len = strlen(str);        
  char *rev = malloc(len + 1);
  if (rev) {
    char *to = rev;
    const char *from = str + len - 1;
    while (from > str) {
      *to++ = *from--;
    }
    *to++ = '\0';
  }
  return rev;
}
```